# Restart countdown by button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a timer counting down and I cannot get it to reset unless the page is refreshed. I am wanting the timer to be reset at the press of the button however I cannot figure out or find the code that is going to help me do this.

Here is the code in my controller

```
Session["Rem_Time"] = null;
if (Session["Rem_Time"] == null)
{
    Session["Rem_Time"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss tt");
}
ViewBag.Rem_Time = Session["Rem_Time"];

return View();
```

Here is the code in the View:

```
<div class="float-left">
    <h2 id="timecountdown"></h2>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="?" />
```

And here is the script for the timer (JS):

```
var dt = '@ViewBag.Rem_Time';
var dateAr = dt.split('-')
var newDate = dateAr[1] + '/' + dateAr[0] + '/' + dateAr[2];

var end = new Date(dateAr[1] + '/' + dateAr[0] + '/' + dateAr[2]);

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert('Countdown Complete!');
        document.getElementById('timecountdown').innerHTML = 'Countdown Ended!';
        return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var _hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var _minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var _seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById('timecountdown').innerHTML = ' Hrs: ' + _hours;
    document.getElementById('timecountdown').innerHTML += ' Mins: ' + _minutes;
    document.getElementById('timecountdown').innerHTML += ' Secs: ' + _seconds;
}
timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

Any help here will be much appreciated!

Comment: create another function which resets the relevant values you use in other method and call that method on `onclick` of the button (ex : `onclick="clearTimer()"`) If you want to update the session value, make an ajax call to do that

Comment: Also `clearInterval(timer)` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by registering the event when a button is clicked and reseting the `h2`.

Example:

```
<div class="float-left">
    <h2 id="timecountdown"></h2>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="reset_counter(5000)" />
```

Now in the script you can add something like...

```
function reset_counter(seconds) {
    // do something with the seconds/minutes/hours...
    document.getElementById("timecountdown").innerHTML = "whatever...";
}
```

Even though looking at your code, you may want to reset the timer rather than the `h2` (anyway, you do know how to do it). Since you application needs, I guess, a time from the server, you may want to retrieve it by using AJAX.

Example:

```
function updateTime() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("timecountdown").innerHTML = "";
            this.responseText;
       }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://myserver.com/foo.asp?time=", true);
    xhttp.send(); 
}
```

I hope this helps.